# Is it still possible to purchase Virtual On on Xbox?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one

I would like to purchase the original [Virtual On Cyber Troops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_On:_Cyber_Troopers) released on Xbox Live Arcade, and I can't find it for sale.

It appears to have been released with something called [Sega Model 2 Collection](https://www.polygon.com/2012/10/18/3523310/sega-model-2-collection-brings-arcade-classics-virtual-on-fighting) but I can't find out whether that was sold as a single item, or a marketing collection.

Can anyone provide me with a link to buy either a physical or digital copy?

It's meant to be backwards compatible on Xbox One, but I'd be happy if I could play on the 360.

Note: I am not after Virtual On OT.